# How to enable debug for specific element in g-streamer for iOS platform?

Tags: ios, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I am trying to send RTMP stream from an iOS device with the following Pipeline but it is failing without giving any error. Is There any way to get more logs to get the issue.

**avfvideosrc ! vtenc_h264 ! h264parse ! flvmux ! queue ! rtmpsink location='rtmp://192.168.11.210/live/livestream**

I have tried **setenv("GST_DEBUG", "*:5", 1)** but no help.

Also if I change **avfvideosrc** to **videotestsrc** pipeline works fine.

*There is no permission issue, As I am able to get data from the camera using **avfvideosrc ! autovideosink** .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd assume that the color spaces don't fit together. H264 encoders usually want YUV 4:2:0 while cams often deliver YUV 4:2:2 or RGB. Try adding a `videoconvert` element between the source and the encoder.

Comment: I have tried with videoconvert also.   I think the issue is with frame size(see in server log below) but if I try to set frame using Capabilities(video/x-raw,format=I420,width=100,height=100,framerate=15/1) with videoconvert data doesn't transmitted.                                                            Server Log: client identified, type=fmle-publish, stream_name=livestream, duration=-1.00
source url=/live/livestream, ip=192.168.11.111, cache=1, is_edge=0, 
start publish mr=0/350, p1stpt=20000, pnt=5000, tcp_nodelay=0, rtcid=161
got metadata, width=4032, height=3024, vcodec=7

Comment: Video dimensions should be a multiple of 16. Encoders can cope with non-multiple with 16 - but it isn't guaranteed. You need to check you encoder hardware what it can do. Just setting capabilities also does not guarantee it is set. If your video source delivers HD and you give it a request for something unsupported it will fail. Your video dimensions in the log seem bogus..

Comment: I have tried 16 multiple Video dimensions. That doesn't work either. Do you know, if there any way I can enable debug for a single element?

Comment: GST_DEBUG=elementname:5 but since *:5 didn't work for you I'm not sure that will help you.

Comment: Got it working with appsrc. The issue was with encoder with some additional flags it started to work(vtenc_h264 bitrate=1000000 max-keyframe-interval-duration=2000000000 max-keyframe-interval=60 allow-frame-reordering=false realtime=true quality=0.5). Not sure what fixed it.  thanks for help.